# stylesheet inherit in QT Designer buttons and widgets

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

I am designing a UI in QT Designer.
I added background image to the main window, and same is inherited to the buttons, and widgets inside the main window,

How can I stop this auto inherit and keep default settings for the objects inside the main window ?

Thanks in Advance !!.

Comment: Use [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```css
.QMainWindow {
    background-image: your image;
}
```